# Как обновить CMake в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio устнавливал через Offline Installer с флагом --noWeb, видимо поэтому, когда я пытаюсь обновить CMake через инсталлер путём его удаления и установки, ничего не меняется. Значит мне нужно самостоятельно скачать cmake и прописать пути к нему? cmake я скачал, но как прописать пути? Не нашёл решения именно для моего случая в интернете

Comment: CMake - это отдельный продукт (https://cmake.org/download/). Может Вы имеете в виду поддержку CMake проектов? Тогда качайте обновленный Offline Installer

Comment: а что насчёт прописывания путей в visual studio к скачанному cmake? это же возможно?

Comment: установщик Cmake - сам прописывает пути до себя. пути до VS - прописывает установщик VS. другого не требуется.  А вообще - Offline Installer - это принципиальное решение? Используйте Community Edition - он бесплатный и вполне хватает, и обновляется нормально сам

Comment: @Ingvar принципиальное так как используется прокси сервер. но и на этом спасибо за пояснение